How do I run Java ProcessBuilder with a "Pipe" to a second exe-file?
If I run this command:
raster2pgsql.exe -I -C -s 4326 -t 256x256 -l 4,16 C:\raster\sthlm.tif public.stockholm | psql -U postgresuser -d rasterdata -h localhost -p 5432
in the windows command line interface, the command executes ok. The raster file is imported to PostgreSQL database "rasterdata".
But I can't get it to work with Java ProcessBuilder. In the command above there are two exe files (raster2pgsql.exe and psql.exe) and I don't know how to define the command for the ProcessBuilder with 2 exe-files.
The syntax for the two programs is:
RASTER2PGSQL:
-s use srid 4326
-I create spatial index
-C use standard raster constraints
-t tile the output 256x256
sthlm.tif input file
-t tile the output 256x256*
public.stockholm load into this table
raster2pgsql -s 4326 -I -C -t 256x256 sthlm.tif public.stockholm > elev.sql
PSQL:
-d connect to this database
-u database user
-h host
-p port
-f read this file after connecting (SQL-output from raster2pgsql)
psql -u postgres -d rasterdata -h localhost -p 5432 -f elev.sql
I don't want to run the programs separately (first storing the converted rasterdata on disk (elev.sql) and then insert the data in elev.sql into the database. Hence I would like to pipe psql to raster2pgsql like Postgis as PostGIS examplifies (https://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html#RT_Raster_Loader):
"A conversion and upload can be done all in one step using UNIX pipes:
raster2pgsql -s 4326 -I -C -M .tif -F -t 100x100 public.demelevation | psql -d gisdb"
This is an example of the outprints when I run my code with raster2pgsql | psql:
INSERT INTO "public"."stockholm | psql -u postgresuser -d rasterdata -h localhost 5432" ("rast") VALUES ('01000...
etc..
it seems that only raster2pgsql is executed
my code:
ArrayList<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>();
cmd.add("raster2pgsql.exe");
cmd.add("-I");
cmd.add("-C");
cmd.add("-s");
cmd.add("4326");
cmd.add("-t");
cmd.add("256x256");
cmd.add("-l");
cmd.add("4,16");
cmd.add(c:\raster\sthlm.tif");
cmd.add("public.stockholm | psql -U postgresuser -d rasterdata -h localhost -p 5432);
ProcessBuilder b = MainDialog.gdalProcess; //pre created
b.command(cmd);
Process p=null;
try {
  p = b.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
try (InputStream processOutput = p.getInputStream()) {
   BufferedReader bufIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(processOutput));
   String str1 = null;
   while ((str1 = bufIn.readLine()) != null) {
       System.out.println(str1 + "\n");
   }
   bufIn.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}


If I run this command:
... in the windows command line interface Since the pipe depends on that very thing (use of the command interpreter) you must do that in your code as well. Therefore the first two arguments to ProcessBuilder should be "cmd.exe" and "/k" I think, strictly speaking, the third might need to be "start" but it might work without

If I add cmd.exe /k start to the command I get  error "Can't find file -I".

I'm not sure what your full command is now. You can simplify your code for the moment until you have it working by just doing the following after filling the command List so you have: new ProcessBuilder(cmd).inheritIO().start();

I am confused by the placement of the closing double-quote in your command.  Did you mean that double-quote to be at the end of the command, or did you mean for it to be at the end of public.stockholm?  If it’s the latter, you can use ProcessBuilder.startPipeline(List.of(new ProcessBuilder("raster2pgsql.exe", "-I", "-C", "-s", "4326", "-t", "256x256", "-l", "4,16", "C:\\raster\\sthlm.tif", "public.stockholm"), new ProcessBuilder("psql", "-U", "postgresuser", "-d", "rasterdata", "-h", "localhost", "-p", "5432"))).

My fault, I've removed the double-quotes. it should not be there in my example. I would like to get processBuilder to execute the command as I do manually in the cmd-window: raster2pgsql.exe -I -C -s 4326 -t 256x256 -l 4,16 C:\raster\sthlm.tif public.stockholm | psql -U postgresuser -d rasterdata -h localhost -p 5432

We seem to be going round in circles. I've already told you how to do that by starting a command interpreter as the basis of that command.

You can test the command out by doing Windows key + R (Start Run) and then pasting in cmd.exe /k raster2pgsql.exe -I -C -s 4326 -t 256x256 -l 4,16 C:\raster\sthlm.tif public.stockholm | psql -U postgresuser -d rasterdata -h localhost -p 5432 and that should run. Your Java should use /c (I think I might have given you the wrong switch earlier sorry)

I got it to work now with ProcessBuilder.startPipeline... (VGR). Thanks for your help, everyone!

You want ProcessBuilder.startPipeline:
ProcessBuilder raster2pgsql = new ProcessBuilder("raster2pgsql.exe",
    "-I", "-C", "-s", "4326", "-t", "256x256", "-l", "4,16",
    "C:\\raster\\sthlm.tif", "public.stockholm");
ProcessBuilder psql = new ProcessBuilder("psql.exe",
        "-h", "localhost", "-p", "5432", "-d", "rasterdata",
        "-U", "postgresuser");

raster2pgsql.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
psql.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
psql.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);

List<Process> pipeline = ProcessBuilder.startPipeline(
    List.of(raster2pgsql, psql));

for (Process process : pipeline) {
    int exitCode = process.waitFor();
    if (exitcode != 0) {
        Optional<String> command = process.info().commandLine();
        if (!command.isPresent()) {
            command = process.info().command();
        }

        throw new IOException("Process exited with code " + exitCode
            + command.map(c -> ": " + c).orElse(""));
    }
}

You cannot pass | directly to a process, since programs never process that character;  it is normally the shell (like bash or cmd.exe) which does that, making the piping of output and input transparent to the programs.  As others have mentioned, a workaround is to pass the entire command to an explicit call to bash or cmd.exe, but then you will have the task of escaping command arguments yourself.  It’s better to let ProcessBuilder.startPipeline take care of everything by passing the sequence of commands directly to the system.
